# DuckDuckGoSearchException: _aget_url() https://links.duckduckgo.com/d.js DuckDuckGoSearchException: Ratelimit

Tags: langchain

I got an error of DuckDuckGoSearchException: _aget_url() https://links.duckduckgo.com/d.js DuckDuckGoSearchException: Ratelimit. Not sure how to fix it? Is there a API for DuckDuckGoSearch? Thanks

```
from agent import load_agent
import streamlit as st

strategy = st.radio(
    "Reasoning strategy",
    ("plan-and-solve", "zero-shot-react", ))

tool_names = st.multiselect(
    'Which tools do you want to use?',
    [
        "google-search", "ddg-search", "wolfram-alpha", "arxiv",
        "wikipedia", "python_repl", "pal-math",
        "llm-math"
    ],
    ["ddg-search", "wolfram-alpha", "wikipedia","google-search"])

agent_chain = load_agent(tool_names=tool_names, strategy=strategy)


DuckDuckGoSearchException: _aget_url() https://links.duckduckgo.com/d.js DuckDuckGoSearchException: Ratelimit
```

Comment: Rate Limit: you're making too many requests too quickly. Fix it by slowing your requests down. For other questions, consult the DuckDuckGo documentation.

Comment: Thanks. How to slow down the requests?